# Subtract Timestamp and get millisecond

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to check if the form is submitted for the last 500 millisecond. If it is submitted then prevent it from submitting. This is for my chat, I need to stop the user for sending the message if his/her last message was send for the last 500 millisecond. It is more on 2 message per second to prevent spamming. Thank You! :)

Comment: You shouldn't do this on the client side only - users could circumvent it to spam the chat nevertheless.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far, and edit your question into an actual question that is not *"plz can u give meh teh codez O_o"*

Comment: I don't mean to offend you, @jroi_web. But I often wonder, why people who are having problems with the simplest matter of saving a variable, doing basic calculation etc. try to create advanced scripts like web chats. I just don't get that! ;)

Comment: @Connum and andy...Thanks for your comments...I will make sure to improve my way of questioning next time..this is just my second question here and I just became a web developer for 6 months now..Im hoping to improve more...GOd bless us guys... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
var start= (new Date()).getTime();
...................
var now = (new Date()).getTime();
var diff = now - start;//diff should be in milis
```

Comment: This is what I am trying to do...Im just not sure if the difference is in milliseconds..thank You for confirming this... :)

Answer (score 3):

In your submit handler, store the time of the last submission. Each time the user submits the form, check the time of the last submission against the current time.

Use the `event.preventDefault()` method to cancel the submission if < 500 ms.

```
$('yourForm').on('submit', function (e) {
    var self = $(this);
    var lastSubmission = self.data('last') || 0;
    var now = (new Date()).getTime();

    if (lastSubmission - now > 500) {
        self.data('last', now);
    } else {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help @matt ...I am a newbie in jquery I didn't understand the part of your code which is the "self.data('last')"..does this mean the "last" is the id or the name of an input box? sorry to bother you but I will try to research on that soon..thank you for your help... :)